# BigDecimal RoundingMode.HALF_UP doesn't work as expected

Tags: java

```
BigDecimal bg = new BigDecimal(0.565));
bg.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toPlainString();
```

result: `0.56` however I am expecting it to be rounded to `0.57` how do I achieve that?

Comment: well see the referenced answer.. Or use `System.out.println(bg);`, it shows what is wrong :O